# WebDriver Exception was unhandled by user code C# NUnit Selenium

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, c#, nunit

Till yeaterday i.e. 17th July 2018 I was able to successfully run my testcases. But now I'm getting below error:

```
A exception with a null response was thrown sending an HTTP request to the remote WebDriver.
```

[server URL.](http://localhost:50475/session/1fe5073098f1c8d894af907bbd8fe832/element/0.23019696033972425-155/selected)

```
The status of the exception was ConnectFailure, and the  
message was: Unable to connect to the remote server"
```

Before this error:

`I was getting "Selenium with C# giving exception Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted" exception.`

I've updated WebDriver and WebDriver Support DLLs.

Can you please help on this.

Comment: Your browser got updated, please use the correct browser driver. Specify which browser and driver version are you using

Comment: @zishanpaya After switching to previous version of Webdriver problem got resolved. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

This issue is due to Browser updates, Please use the updated driver or downgrade the browser to older version.